# What does a family do for charging and storage of multiple Apple devices?

Tags: charging, storage

What does a family with multiple devices do for charging and storage of a growing number of devices.  We now have 4 laptops 5 iPads and 5 iPhones plus several other iPods. Are there any cabinets designed for the home that can charge and house this many?  I am tired of the cords and devices laying all over my house.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Apple stackexchange. Thank you for providing some information on your problem. Could you also add to your question what sort of laptops you have? MacBook Pro? MacBook Air? etc... This will make it easier for the users to provide you with a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

I find the cables die pretty frequently. The kids always get them knotted, or stress them. So, I buy a lot of cheap ones. [Something like these.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0030LQFJG) At $4 for 5 I tend to buy 15-20 a time. Takes months to run through them and I don't fret about it. We have a huge stock of the actual little bricks from the many iPhones we've had.

I've also seen a lot of interesting little projects for charging and cable management:

- [DIY Charging Cell Phone Holder](http://blog.al.com/bargain-mom/2012/03/frugal_home_organization_diy_c.html)
- [Desk Phone Charger Holder](http://www.chezlarsson.com/myblog/2012/09/desk-phone-charger-holder.html)

The neatest/simplest being:

- [Neatly Organize USB Cables and Charging Cords on your Desk](http://www.labnol.org/gadgets/reduce-cable-clutter-on-desktop/13270/)

Also several items like this on the market:

- [Bamboo Charging Station](http://www.skymall.com/shopping/detail.htm?pid=204042658&c=)

And finally, I'm putting these by the bed so my phone can charge over night:

- [U-Socket USB Wallplug](https://www.thinkgeek.com/product/e81a/)

Comment: Thanks for doing research on this topic, you got some very interesting stuff here. Is there a special reason why you included the links in a way which makes them unclickable?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily Apple-specific (I don't believe there is a mass Apple-friendly charging station), but a cheaper option would be to consolidate all of the cables into one space. For example, you can have a power strip with USB-compatibility in one area of your house and have your family charge their devices there. For example, I have a device like [this](http://img.diytrade.com/cdimg/596248/5296569/0/1262611766/E-Bar_Advanced_Socket_Power_Strip_builtin_USB_HUB.jpg) that suits all of my charging needs.